# Javascript Promises - save item before for loop

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, parse-platform, cloud, promise

I have a parse cloud code function, in this function I preform a query on some items then using a for loop I save some of those items. But the for loop continues and does not save some of the items before correctly.

Heres a general version of the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveCurrentDayItems", function(request, response) {
var xmlReader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

var MenuURL = Parse.Object.extend("MenuURL");
var queryMenuURL = new Parse.Query(MenuURL);
queryMenuURL.find().then(function(resultsMenuURL) {
//********************************************************************************************************
//I want the save to happen before it goes thought this for loop for the second time, and so on
        for (var i = 0; i < resultsMenuURL.length; i++) { 
            var location = resultsMenuURL[i].get("Location");
            Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: url,
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    var xmlData = httpResponse.text;
                    xmlReader.read(xmlData, function (err, res){
                        if(err) return console.log(err);
                            for (var i3 = 0; i3 < res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal.count(); i3++) {
                                var meal = res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal.at(i3).attributes().name;
                                testItem.set("meal", meal);
                                testItem.set("location", location);
                                testItem.save().then(function(testItem) {
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                }
            });
        }           
});
});
```

I have looked at the parse docs, but I can't make sense of them, the promises section I just can't grasp.

Thanks so much for the help in advance

EDIT 2

When I have your code like this I get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'reduce' of undefined`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveCurrentDayItems23", function(request, response) {
var xmlReader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

//First worker function, promisify xmlReader.read();
function readResponse_async(xlmString) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    xmlReader.read(xlmString, function (err, res) {
        if(err) {
            promise.reject(err);
        } else {
            promise.resolve(res);
            results = res;
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

//Second worker function, perform a series of saves
function saveMeals_async(meals, location, testItem) {
    return meals.reduce(function(promise, meal) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            testItem.set("meal", meal.attributes().name);
            //the line above does not work it cannot get meal, it is undefined
            testItem.set("location", location);
            return testItem.save();
        });
    }, Parse.Promise.as());
}

var MenuURL = Parse.Object.extend("MenuURL");
var queryMenuURL = new Parse.Query(MenuURL);

//Master routine
queryMenuURL.find().then(function(resultsMenuURL) {

    for (var i = 0; i < resultsMenuURL.length; i++) {

        var url = resultsMenuURL[i].get('URL');
        return resultsMenuURL.reduce(function(promise, item) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    url: url,
                    //data: ... //some properties of item?
                }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                    return readResponse_async(httpResponse.text).then(function() {
                        var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
                        var testItem = new TestItem();
                        return saveMeals_async(result.menu.day.meal.counter.dish.name.text(),item.get("Location"), 
    testItem);
//this line above does not work, it sends only one string, not an array, so reduce cannot be called
                    });
                });
            });
        }, Parse.Promise.as());
    }
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
});
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to be a lot more specific about what exactly the problem is and what exactly you want help with.  Please refer to specific portions of your code, describe what you want it to do and explain what is happening currently that is different than that.  For example, you say you want a save to happen before the first `for` loop, but the only code that appears to have anything to do with a save is buried deep inside not only that `for` loop, but also another one embedded in it.  It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay trying to be as specific as possible. I have this query that returns a few URL's and then, from these urls get an http request so I can parse some data. Once I have parsed some of this data I want to save some of the original data and some of the parsed data. And my objective is to save the data before the for loop runs again? does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do as the question asks ("I want the save to happen before it goes [through] this for loop for the second time, and so on"), is fairly involved - not really a beginners' problem.

It appears that you have several async operations here, viz :

- `queryMenuURL.find()`
- `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()`
- `xmlReader.read()`
- `testItem.save()`

These operations need to work in cooperation with each other to give the desired effect.

`queryMenuURL.find()`, `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()` and `testItem.save()` each appear to return a promise, while `xmlReader.read()` takes a node style callback, which makes things slightly awkward but not too bad.

You could write the code as one big block but you would end up with patterns within patterns. To make everything readable, you can pull out some of the code as (readabe) worker functions, leaving behind a (readable) master routine.

To convert your current outer `for` loop to set of sequential operations, you need the following pattern, which exploits `Array.prototype.reduce()` to build a `.then` chain, and returns a promise :

```
function doThings_async(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(promise, item) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            return doSomething_async(item, result);
        });
    }, resolvedPromise);
}
```

You will see below that this pattern is also used for the inner `for` loop, though other possibilities exist.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveCurrentDayItems", function(request, response) {
    var xmlReader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

    //First worker function, promisify xmlReader.read();
    function readResponse_async(xlmString) {
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();
        xmlReader.read(xlmString, function (err, res) {
            if(err) {
                promise.reject(err);
            } else {
                promise.resolve(res);
            }
        }
        return promise;
    }

    //Second worker function, perform a series of saves
    function saveMeals_async(meals, location, testItem) {
        return meals.reduce(function(promise, meal) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                testItem.set("meal", meal.attributes().name);
                testItem.set("location", location);
                return testItem.save();
            });
        }, Parse.Promise.as());
    }

    var MenuURL = Parse.Object.extend("MenuURL");
    var queryMenuURL = new Parse.Query(MenuURL);

    //Master routine
    queryMenuURL.find().then(function(resultsMenuURL) {
        ...
        return resultsMenuURL.reduce(function(promise, item) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    url: url,
                    //data: ... //some properties of item?
                }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                    return readResponse_async(httpResponse).then(function() {
                        return saveMeals_async(res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal, item.get("Location"), testItem);
                    });
                });
            });
        }, Parse.Promise.as());
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

`saveMeals_async()` *could* be written to perform its saves in parallel rather than in series, but it depends on what you want. For parallel saves, only `saveMeals_async()` would need to be rewritten, using a different pattern.

### EDIT

Revised code based on the edits in the question.

Due to changes in `saveMeals_async()`, the `arr.reduce(...)` pattern is now used only once in the master routine.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveCurrentDayItems", function(request, response) {
    // ***
    // insert all the Date/dayNumber code here
    // ***
    var xmlReader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

    //First worker function, promisify xmlReader.read();
    function readResponse_async(xlmString) {
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();
        xmlReader.read(xlmString, function (err, res) {
            if(err) {
                promise.reject(err);
            } else {
                promise.resolve(res);
            }
        }
        return promise;
    }

    //Second worker function, perform a series of saves
    function saveMeals_async(meals, school, diningHallNumber, menuLocation) {
        //Declare all vars up front
        var i3, i4, i5, m,
            TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem"),//can be reused within the loops?
            promise = Parse.Promise.as();//resolved promise to start a long .then() chain
        for (i3 = 0; i3 < meals.count(); i3++) {
            m = meals.at(i3);
            //get number of stations in day
            for (i4 = 0; i4 < m.counter.count(); i4++) {
                //get number of items at each station
                for (i5 = 0; i5 < m.counter.at(i4).dish.count(); i5++) {
                    //Here a self-executing function is used to form a closure trapping `testItem`.
                    //Otherwise the `testItem` used in `promise.then(...)` would be the last 
                    //remaining `testItem` created when all iterations are complete.
                    (function(testItem) {
                        testItem.set("item", m.counter.at(i4).dish.at(i5).name.text());
                        testItem.set("meal", m.attributes().name);
                        testItem.set("school", school);
                        testItem.set("diningHallNumber", diningHallNumber);
                        testItem.set("schoolMenu", menuLocation);
                        //build the .then() chain
                        promise = promise.then(function() {
                            return testItem.save();
                        });
                    })(new TestItem());
                });
            }
        }
        return promise;
    }

    var MenuURL = Parse.Object.extend("MenuURL");
    var queryMenuURL = new Parse.Query(MenuURL);

    //Master routine
    queryMenuURL.find().then(function(resultsMenuURL) {
        return resultsMenuURL.reduce(function(promise, menuItem) {
            var url = menuItem.get('URL'),
                school = menuItem.get("school"),
                diningHallNumber = menuItem.get("diningHallNumber"),
                menuLocation = menuItem.get("menuLocation");
            return promise.then(function() {
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    url: url,
                    //data: ... //some properties of menuItem?
                }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                    return readResponse_async(httpResponse).then(function(res) {
                        if (res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal) {
                            return saveMeals_async(res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal, school, diningHallNumber, menuLocation);
                        } else {
                            return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }, Parse.Promise.as());
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

*untested so may well need debugging*

Comment: I am having some trouble following the code, what is that "..." and could u add some more comments maybe, I have added my full version of the original code above, as I have multiple xmlStrings. and where does the function do this async go?

Comment: I am starting to understand the code more and more but I am getting an error on line 44, that says res is not defined

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake that will give that `res` error. Leave it with me, I will post some revised code for you, taking your edits into account.

Comment: Okay its very close, but I get this error: `Error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'` I think it is because this line `m.counter.at(i4).dish` doesn't return an array

Comment: here is an example of the xml if it helps http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/university_of_albany/uAlbanyAlumniMenu.xml

Comment: Yes you are correct. I thought we were dealing with arrays here. Several workarounds are possible. I have chosen to revert to `for(...)` and form a deliberate closure to trap `testItem`. Answer edited above. If you don't understand closure then try search stackOverflow for a definition - there are several good answers.

Comment: hey roamer I am working on this same script I got a question with 150 bounty on it, and I need it to handle a url that is broken, how would I add that, here is the link to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677920/javascript-uncaught-a-promise-was-rejected-even-though-it-had-already-been-reje I would really appreciate your help

Comment: just wondering if you think this could be done? And if you are interested in doing it?