# Javascript -Uncaught A promise was rejected even though it had already been rejected

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have this Parse.com cloud code job, that I am running. It queries one of my classes and gets url's, then I read these urls, which are xml files, and I get some data from them and save it to parse. As can be seen in the code.

Here is the code

Full code here  [gist.github.com/gouegd/aae61aa08b8295d52b08](https://gist.github.com/gouegd/aae61aa08b8295d52b08)

When I run this cloud code job. In the console. I see this message

`Failed with: Uncaught A promise was rejected even though it had already been rejected.`

This is coming up because some of the urls are not valid, and then the code breaks.

Basically I need a way to handle it when one of the URL isn't working and not have the code stop!! And continue with the other urls.

This problem occurs between line 77-83, where the url variable is being passed, so I need it to ignore bad urls and then keep going with the rest of the urls.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your promise usage looks correct.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum do you think the problem might be somewhere else I don't see how it could?

Comment: Can you show us saveMeals_async?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum here is full code https://gist.github.com/spennyf/5fa387ebd3e8aa6d11fc

Comment: From shallow reading - you seem to understand promises very well and to use promise concurrency patterns correctly. I don't see an 'obvious' flaw, my only suggestion is to step through the code with a debugger one item at a time - this might as well be a parse issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah I have logged it one line a part, and they just disappear which is why I'm so confused?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64059/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Comment: @iqueqiorio, try chaining a `.catch()` after the innermost `then` and returning `Parse.Promise.as()` (again), to keep the promise chain going. If that doesn't work, move the catch out by one `then()`, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, no `.catch()` in parse - has to be `.then(null, function() ...)`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Are you talking about replace then then at line 77 in the gist with that?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting you try chaining a diagnostic `.then(null, function(e) (console.error(e)))` at 90, 91 or 92, though on reflection it's unlikely to inform you of anything that your terminal 'fail' doesn't already tell you.

Comment: We can imagine either one of your URLs fail to load, or the line `res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal` throws an error (accessing a property of undefined) and results in a rejected promise. In any case it would help to track down which is the promise that gets rejected first, by adding error callbacks.

Comment: @Greg how would I do that? If one of the urls is wrong how could I get around, having a bad url but it continue for the rest of them?

Comment: The reduce trick is pretty smart though, if I get it right it processes each menu URL one after another, as long as there's no error. In your case there's an error at the 16th URL apparently, so it gets rejected and all the later "then" callbacks will be ignored (which is why you see no more logs). If that's no what you actually want, you may want to process all URLs in parallel regardless of the other URLs' success or failure (which means that possible only URL 16 would fail, if the others are fine).

Comment: @Greg what would I need to change to get that, so that if one url fails, it gets the rest still?

Comment: @iqueqiorio on every `then` call, you currently have one callback (the success callback). Add a second argument which is an error callback. Log them with different messages so you know where the error is triggered first.

Comment: @Greg sorry, not quite sure what your saying could you add that to my code?

Comment: see line 92 here https://gist.github.com/gouegd/aae61aa08b8295d52b08 . You can reproduce this to add more error loggers. Note here I return a value from the handler, so this results in a resolved promise again (the error was intercepted). This means that all 25 URLs should be processed regardless of each one's outcome.

Comment: @Greg okay that worked but it logged a couple urls twice?

Comment: @iqueqiorio you do log them at line 72 and 78. Those logged twice are the ones that do not fail to load.

Comment: @Greg I am still getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64184/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-greg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird error message.

As far as I can tell ...

Between lines 89 and 90 insert :

```
    }, function() {
        return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
```

to give :

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    //data: ... //some properties of menuItem?
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    return readResponse_async(httpResponse.text).then(function(res) {
        if (res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal) {

            return saveMeals_async(res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal, school, diningHallNumber, menuLocation);
        } else {
            return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
        }
    }, function() {
        return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
    });
});
```

or maybe one line lower :

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    //data: ... //some properties of menuItem?
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    return readResponse_async(httpResponse.text).then(function(res) {
        if (res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal) {

            return saveMeals_async(res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal, school, diningHallNumber, menuLocation);
        } else {
            return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
        }
    });
}, function() {
    return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
});
```

**EDIT**

As both of those have failed to handle the error, you might try this, which is messy but tolerable if, as I suspect, Parse's promises are not "throw-safe" :

```
return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    //data: ... //some properties of menuItem?
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    try {
        return readResponse_async(httpResponse.text).then(function(res) {
            if (res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal) {
                return saveMeals_async(res.menu.day.at(dayNumber).meal, school, diningHallNumber, menuLocation);
            } else {
                throw new Error();
            }
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
    }
}, function() {
    return Parse.Promise.as();//return resolved promise to keep the promise chain going.
});
```

Comment: I have posted the code with your edit here just to make sure I got it right. https://gist.github.com/spennyf/5fa387ebd3e8aa6d11fc. But this still gave the error.

Comment: I may be a line out. Try removing those two lines and reinserting between lines 90 and 91. That should handle a `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()` error. If that still doesn't work, then you have to be suspicious that `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()` is successful and the error is thrown from the success handler.

Comment: could you add it in I am having trouble seeing where you want me to add it.

Comment: It still stops at the url that is broken here is the broken url if that helps, http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/binghamton_university/binghamton_university_hinman_menu.xml

Comment: The problem is that the server is returning a "successful" HTTP response under an error condition and readResponse_async() attempts to parse it as if it were genuinely successful; and it would appear that Parse's promises are not "throw safe". The solution lies in (a) server-side - returning a genuine error (400 series); (b) making `readResponse_async()` tolerant of the error response; (c) making te master routine tolerant of readResponse_async's lack of tolerance. I will make another edit above based on (c).

Comment: Maybe @BenjaminGruenbaum (hot in this area) can advise on a better approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64423/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-roamer-1888).